Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://someurl", local:"someNewElementsFromResponse"). Expected elements are <{}>
I'm getting >Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://someurl", local:"someNewElementsFromResponse"). Expected elements are <{}>  while consuming SOAP based webservice using Spring boot camel integration.
below is the sample
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>src/main/resources/accounts.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

and we are using below Spring boot config for routing.

@Component
public class CamelRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:fetchAccountsDetails")
            .bean(AccountsRequestBuilder.class)
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME,
                    constant("fetchAccountDetails"))
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE,
                    constant("http://demo.namespace.com"))
            .to("cxf://http://localhost:808/dummyUrl?serviceClass=com.demo.service.wsdl.AccountPortType&wsdlURL=accounts.wsdl")
            .end()
            .process("accountDetailsProcessor"); // Spring component

            //..... some other routers

}


template code

public class Request {
@Autowired
private org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;


public <T> T makeCameRequest(String route, Object userDetails, Class<T> responseType) throws
        Throwable {
    try {
        return producerTemplate.requestBody(route, userDetails, responseType);
    } catch (CamelExecutionException e) {
        log.error("error : {}", e);
    }
}

}
// processor class

@Component("accountDetailsProcessor")
public class AccountDetailsProcessor implements Processor {
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Accounts accounts = exchange.getIn().getBody
            (Accounts.class);
    // .... some other codes

}

}
is there any way to ignore any unknown element in Apache Camel Spring boot.
Camel version: 3.6.0
Spring: 2.7.5
JDK11
